# How to find the 'best' path(s) between two points on a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

I was watching a TV programme about hiking trails; they were talking about [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_Vandelli), and mentioned that the guy who directed the construction work was a mathematician, 'hence' he could calculate the 'best' path.

That made me wonder: **what specific mathematical techniques would help with that?**

I found [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_design_of_roads), which clearly shows that matters are quite complicated, due to several considerations (like safety, environmental impact, etc) and contingent constraints (like not going through some urban areas, etc) in addition to the purely geometric aspect.

Even aside of those considerations, I would not immediately know how to solve the problem in its simplest and unconstrained form, assuming e.g. that 'best' = 'shortest':

> *given a surface described as $F(x,y,z) = 0$, and two points $A (x_A, y_A, z_A), B (x_B, y_B, z_B)$ on it, how do you find the shortest path between $A$ and $B$ (that is also all on the surface)?*

You could add as an additional constraint that the absolute value of the slope of the path must never exceed a given value, say $0.2$.

And I suppose there may be more than one solution when $F(x,y,z)$ is quite uneven.

I imagine this problem is well-known, but I don't know what it is called / where to find the info.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the tags added to your post and you'll get a rather good idea of where to find more info. Also, this question is possibly better suited for Math.SE

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical approach here is to use the Euler Lagrange equations.

You need to define some kind of cost function as a function of the location and direction. For example, you could penalize paths by location in urban areas or are environmentally sensitive. You could have another term that penalizes paths by their length and direction.

This leads to a series of differential equations that the optimal path would have to satisfy. These along with the the initial and final point wiod let you narrow it down to a finite of local optima. You can then choose the best out of these.

However, this is a fairly poor approach to the problem. It’s going to be very difficult (impossible) to solve these differential equations exactly unless your geometry is really simple, so it’ll be difficult to numerically find the right initial direction to go in the right direction.

A better approach is to quantize your space and use a standard path finding algorithm like A*. One possibility is  to define a grid over your space, allow for transitioning between adjacent locations, and adding a cost for every location you visit based on it’s goodness and every edge between adjacent nodes you take based on geography and conditions. There are many many variations of this approach to account for varying circumstances including getting diagonals better. Here’s one explanation of a representing a map as a graph or series of hierarchical graphs to speed this up: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/MapRepresentations.html](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/MapRepresentations.html)

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting, especially the A* algorithm. For the record, I had posted a comment when my own OP was still on physics SE, mentioning that 'geodesic' returned this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708146/shortest-path-between-two-points-on-a-surface. I guess the guy who designed the road in the 18th century did not know about these methods; if so, he must have used something simpler that was available at the time. The TV programme vaguely mentioned 'triangles'. Hmm...